# Get string after last "." that may contain "."

Tags: javascript, split

I've got this string:

```
λx.λy.Math.pow(x,y)
```

And I want to get:

```
Math.pow(x,y)
```

Basically everything after the last `.` with a `λ`. The last part may also contain a `λ`.

```
λx.λy.print("λ"+x+".λ"+y)
```

Comment: This is a case to write a parser. Plus, it's going to be impossible to get right without a properly defined grammar.

Comment: Before this can be solved, you have to define some rules for which `.` is the last one to trigger the split and which is not.  You've given multiple conflicting examples so far with no clear algorithm.  So, if you define the algorithm, folks here can offer code for it, but we cannot define the algorithm because we do not know your requirements or all possible inputs/desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regexp should work:

```
/((λ.+?)\.)+([^λ].*)/
```

The regexp expects a sequence of words beginning with `λ`, separated by `.` until it finds a word that does not begin with `λ`. When that word is found, the last group is matched - the group that you're looking for.

Example:

```
var
    re = /((λ.+?)\.)+([^λ].*)/,
    m,
    test1 = 'λx.λy.Math.pow(x,y)',
    test2 = 'λx.λy.print("λ"+x+".λ"+y)',
    test3 = 'λx.λy.λx.λy.λx.λfoo.λa.λz.print("λ"+x+".λ"+y)';

console.info(test1.match(re).pop()); // prints 'Math.pow(x,y)'
console.info(test2.match(re).pop()); // prints 'print("λ"+x+".λ"+y)'
console.info(test3.match(re).pop()); // prints 'print("λ"+x+".λ"+y)'
```

You should always look for the last group. Of course, you should check for a match first:

```
var
    re = /((λ.+?)\.)+([^λ].*)/,
    m,
    test4 = "won't match";

m = test4.match(re);

if (m) {
    console.info(m.pop());
} else {
    console.info('No match found');
}
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/luciopaiva/0ty4z2kb/